# How to turn comma-separated lists within a list into integers?

Tags: python

For instance, I have a list like this:

`AD= ['3,7', '6,7', '17,16', '16,23', '9,10']`

And I want to turn each of the strings into integers, without getting rid of the fact that they're a pair. So I DON'T want it to turn into:

`AD= [3, 7, 6, 7, 17, 16, 16, 23, 9, 10]`

I've already tried the following but it didn't work:

```
         for i in AD:
            val= i.split(",")
            for j in val:
               j= map(int, j)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself before posting. If you get stuck on something specific, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried, so we can help.

Answer (score 1):

As simple as :

```
>>> [ tuple(map(int, x.split(','))) for x in AD ]
=> [(3, 7), (6, 7), (17, 16), (16, 23), (9, 10)]
```

This will conserve your need for `pair` as a `list of tuples`.

Here we are going through the `list`, `splitting` the string based on the delimiter `','` and then putting them together as a `tuple` after converting the values to `int` .

Comment: When I try applying this function for a list of doubles, (replaced "int" with "float" in the above function) it doesn't work. How would I adapt it for a list like `AF=['0.27, 0.56', '0.24, 0.06', '0.44, 0.35']`

Comment: Hmmm. Are you sure? I tried just now and it works. Gave me : `[(0.27, 0.56), (0.24, 0.06), (0.44, 0.35)]`

Comment: @claudiadast what is it that you get when you try with float? Is it an error or some other output? The code is : `[ tuple(map(float, x.split(','))) for x in AF ]`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import itertools
AD= ['3,7', '6,7', '17,16', '16,23', '9,10']
final = list(map(int, itertools.chain.from_iterable([b.split(",") for b in AD])))
```

Output:

```
[3, 7, 6, 7, 17, 16, 16, 23, 9, 10]
```

If you want to conserve the original pairs:

```
import re
AF=['0.27, 0.56', '0.24, 0.06', '0.44, 0.35']
final_data = [tuple(map(float, re.split(",\s*", i))) for i in AF]
```

Output:

```
[(0.27, 0.56), (0.24, 0.06), (0.44, 0.35)]
```

Comment: Thanks, @Ajax1234, but I wanted to conserve the original pairs of numbers, which will be lost in that output

Comment: What do you mean you want to conserve pairs? Do you want '3,7' -> 37 or do you want them to be a tuple (3,7)?

Comment: @bhow: yes I want it to be a tuple

Comment: @Ajax1234: When I try applying this function for a list of doubles, (replaced "int" with "float" in the above function) it doesn't work. How would I adapt it for a list like `AF=['0.27, 0.56', '0.24, 0.06', '0.44, 0.35']`

Comment: @claudiadast please see my recent edit. Note that my changes will work for lists contain both integers and floats.

Answer (score 0):

A trustworthy function, although it does not handle conversion to ints back and spaces after commas.

```
def pairize_inplace(iterable, splitter=','):
    for i in range(len(iterable)):
        iterable[i] = str(iterable[i].split(splitter))
```